# Password and Confirm on Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to create the tool to confirm the password in the ionic but it is not working. The same code worked on another project. But I guess perhaps I was using Ionic 2.

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label stacked>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="usuario.password" validateEqual="confirmPassword" reverse="true" #password="ngModel" required>
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <p ion-text [hidden]="password.valid || submitted == false" color="danger" padding-left>
            Password required
        </p>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label stacked>Confirm password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" [(ngModel)]="usuario.confirmPassword" validateEqual="password" reverse="false" #confirmPassword="ngModel" required>
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <p ion-text [hidden]="confirmPassword.valid || (confirmPassword.pristine && submitted == false)" color="danger" padding-left>
            Incompatible password
        </p>
```

Could anyone try to help me with this?

Comment: What is the current behaviour of this part of code ? Does it always show 'Incompatible password' ?

Comment: No, it just accepts the other password normally as if it were the same.

Comment: So, did you try to change validateEqual="password" for validateEqual="usuario.password" in your control field ? And same for the first field too...

Comment: Still not working as before.

Comment: Well... Is there something special in your controller ? And, not sure, but ngModel seems to be a property of Ionic 2 (3) and not Ionic 1 that use ng-model